# Json element loading issue with python

Tags: python, json

This is how i am dumping data to a json file with python

```
    data ['username'] = username

    data ['password'] = password

    with open(soDB, 'wb') as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp)
        print 'dumping'
```

This is how i am trying to restore the data

```
    with open(soDB, 'rb') as fp:
        jdata = json.load(fp)               
        print jdata


    for element in jdata: 
       password =  element["password"]  
       username =  element[ "username"]
```

But i keep getting error.. Sorry not used to json..
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show us the error/backtrace?

Comment: it says "string indices must be integers"

Comment: Please, may you show us what `print jdata` returns? I suppose you can get what you want simply using `jdata['username']` (no for loop needed)

Comment: I am giving it a try..

Comment: Yes..thanks...just jdata['username'] is fine...

Answer (score 0):

```
username = jdata['username']
password= jdata['password']
```

No need for element loop.